# SimpleCart JS Cart Image Undefined

Tags: javascript, image, undefined, cart, simplecart

I'm a newbie here so hoping someone can help. I'm using simplecart and cant seem to get the cart image to display, the cart image shows as undefined. I have tried all of the suggested work around's I've found on here but no joy.

my html markup:

```
<div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
    <img src="images/clothingmens/1001.jpg" class="item-thumb">
    <p class="item_name"> Oneill Hoody</p><span class="item_price">&pound;59.00</span>
    <p><select class="item_size">
        <option value="0">Select Size</option>
        <option value="Small"> Small </option>
        <option value="Medium"> Medium </option>
        <option value="Large"> Large </option>
        </select></br>
    <a class="item_add" href="javascript:;"> Add to Cart </a></p>
                            </div>
```

My Javascript:

```
            settings = {
                checkout                : { type: "PayPal", email: "removed" },
                currency                : "GBP",
                language                : "english",
                cartStyle               : "table",
                cartColumns         : [
                    {view:'image' , attr:'thumb', label: false},
                    { attr: "name", label: "Name" },
                    { attr: "price", label: "Price", view: 'currency' },
                    { attr: "size", label: "Size" },
                    { attr: "quantity", label: "Qty" },
                    { attr: "total", label: "SubTotal", view: 'currency' },
                    { view: "remove", text: "Remove", label: false }                
                ],



                shippingFlatRate        : 0,
                shippingQuantityRate    : 0,
                shippingTotalRate       : 0,
                shippingCustom      : null,

                taxRate             : 0,
                
                taxShipping         : false,

                data                : {}

            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay. lol. so in your image tag

```
<img src="images/clothingmens/1001.jpg" class="item-thumb">
```

add 'item_image' to the class.

```
<img src="images/clothingmens/1001.jpg" class="item-thumb item_image">
```

That should fix it. good luck!

also, im not sure, but you may have to add the 'thumb tag'

```
<img src="images/clothingmens/1001.jpg" class="item-thumb item_image" thumb="images/clothingmens/1001.jpg">
```

hope this helps!